Is it a good practice to have language specific materialized views?
Ok I have a recipe db. One recipe is written in multiple languages.
Now I want to search in my recipes. Lets say I have 50.000 recipes. Because of performance I want to build materialized views.
Now what do I do? Do I create one materialized view that holds:
name_en, name_de, name_es, ts_vector_en, ts_vector_de, ts_vector_es

Or would I just create three separate ones?

More details are needed to understand what problem you're trying to solve with materialized views, in order to answer how you should use them.

50000 is not that big, so such considerations about speed seem unecessry

@nbk thank you!
